# Prove that the incomplete quotient and the remainder at division in $\mathbb {Z} [i]$ are defined ambiguously.

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

I was told that it is possible to understand this by finding at least two ways to divide with a remainder $3+2i$ by $1+i$ (ex. $(3+2i) \div (1+i)$), but i don't really understand how this will help me.

Comment: Please define what you mean by incomplete quotient and what does it mean for it to be ambiguous.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang unfortunately I do not know how to translate it properly into English, but if i'm right I have to prove that the quotient and the remainder of the division (for example, if we talk about integers, when we divide 9 by 5, we get that the quotient = 1 and the remainder = 4) in $\mathbb {Z} [i]$. About "ambiguous": for example, when we take the root of a complex number we get several answers. My textbooks write this down as "the result is ambiguously defined".

Comment: @ShengtongZhang  A Euclidean domain has only existence of quotient and remainder, not uniqueness ("unambiguous" refers to uniqueness).

Comment: I see! So I made a mistake...

Comment: So we have $(3 + 2i) = 2(1 + i) + 1$ and $(3 + 2i) = 3(1 + i) + (-1)$ and $(3 + 2i) = (2 - i)(1 + i) + i$, and all are valid division-with-remainder w.r.t to the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang thank you! I finally figured out how to write it down. I'll add the solution to this question a little later. Just tell me, please, how do I close the question after that?

Comment: You don't close questions, you just write a complete solution and leave the question-solution there.